# Flutter Google Sing-In with FirebaseAuth

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

Currntly in the app we're using FirebaseAuth for authentication with email. I'm trying to add to the app Google Sign-In. I've seen that for doing this I need to add SHA-1 certificate fingerprint to android app in the firebase project settings.
As I understand I need to add SHA-1 certificate fingerprint for debug version of the app. For this I need to add certificate fingerprint from my local machine.
So I have a few questions:

Does it mean that other developers that are working on this project also should add certificate fingerprints from their local machines to the firebase project, so they will be able to use Google Sign-In during debug?

Do I also need to add some other SHA-1 certificate fingerprint to be able test the app in the release mode or if I install it from APK?

Currently our app is added to the google play, so in this case I also need to add one more SHA-1 certificate fingerprint?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the both release and debug SHA keys in the firebase.

release SHA key enables the google sign-in functionality in the release mode of the app i.e. while building to upload in the google play store.

The debug SHA key is generated via the code and it does not depend on your local machine.

Once generated and added the SHA key in firebase, there should be no additional changes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What about `App signing key certificate` from Google Play Console. As I understand it also should be added to the firebase project, so it will be available if app is installed via Google Play? Or release key should be enough for it?

Comment: you do not have to add any certificates. It will be done automatically the first time you publish the app